# Powershell Putty Connection and Automating Tasks

Tags: powershell, batch-file, putty

I want to use PowerShell to connect to a PuTTY "saved session" and then specify a file that contains some batch commands.  Using CMD this would look like

```
d:\putty\psftp 'Saved Session Name' -b d:\location.txt.
```

I think that the PS equivalent should look like

```
Start-Process d:\putty\psftp.exe 'Saved Session Name' 
(and then a call to pass a 'get' script) i.e. cd Outgoing get <date>.txt
```

However, I get the following error:

```
a positional parameter cannot be found that accepts the argument
```

How can I accomplish this using PowerShell?

Comment: You don't necessarily need Start-Process.  What happens when you try to run `d:\putty\psftp.exe 'Saved Session Name' -b d:\location.txt` from Powershell?  The biggest catch is if you have spaces in path names.  You might need to use quotes and the call operator: `&"d:\putty\psftp.exe" 'Saved Session Name' -b "d:\location.txt"`.

Comment: Updated my comment to an answer and added some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't necessarily need Start-Process.

What happens when you try to run `d:\putty\psftp.exe 'Saved Session Name' -b d:\location.txt` from Powershell? The first thing I do is try it exactly like I'd run it from the command line.

The biggest catch is if you have spaces in path names. You might need to use quotes and the call operator (ampersand): `&"d:\putty\psftp.exe" 'Saved Session Name' -b "d:\location.txt"`.

If you do need to use Start-Process, you can do this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "d:\putty\psftp.exe" `
    -ArgumentList "'Saved Session Name' -b d:\location.txt" -Wait
```

Or like this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "d:\putty\psftp.exe" `
    -ArgumentList 'Saved Session Name', '-b', "d:\location.txt" -Wait
```

Note that the argument list in the first is a single string with every argument in it, and in the second it is an array of strings with one string for every argument.  Everything needs to be in the same order that they'd be on the command line, and it's not uncommon for it to be a bit flaky.  Usually one method or the other works better, but it depends on the application you're calling.  Usually with quotes and spaces in path names because you're going through multiple levels of escaping depending on the program you're calling (noticing a theme?).

I added the `-Wait` parameter to my code above because, by default, Start-Process continues to the next line without waiting since it actually spawns a separate process.  `-Wait` forces Powershell to, well, wait, which is what people usually want in a non-interactive script.

See `Get-Help about_Operators` or `Get-Help "call operator"` for more topics for help with the call operator.  See `Get-Help Start-Process` for help with that.

Comment: I receive 'unable to open connection to putty_loc -host does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

All you need is `plink`:

```
plink 'Saved Session Name'
```

Comment: I get a rubbish terminal: ←[0m←[27m←[24m←[J←[36mroot - raspberrypi ←[33m ~ ←[36m←[00m←[K←[?1h←=←[?2004h \n Due to lack of memory on the rasp or my host system win 10?

Comment: Amazing. With this, I can use PS to SSH to my Linux server using a nicer [terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N0DX20HK701) than CMD prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the below Technet Wiki link which contains various ways to run executables in PowerShell.

[PowerShell: Running Executables](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$Path = "d:\putty\psftp.exe" 
$Prm1 = 'Saved Session Name'
$Prm2 = "-b"
$Prm3 = "d:\location.txt"

&$Path $Prm1 $Prm2 $Prm3
```